# ahref javascript window.print add a name

Tags: javascript, href

I got the following code which works.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()"><img src="images/print.png" border="0"</a>
```

But I want to combine it with this code.

```
onClick="document.title = "My new title";window.print();"
```

I have tried:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()" onClick="document.title = "My new title";"><img src="images/print.png" border="0"</a>
```

But it is not working!

Comment: Please do **not** add a solution to your question. If one of the answers helped you mark it as accepted, otherwise make a new answer with your solution.

Comment: I will do that but for some reason you need to wait 8 mins before an answer can be accepted!!! But i added the solution so that people could copy paste the entire a href line. In your answer which is the right answer there is only the onclick part visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not escape your double quotes.

Try using single quotes instead:

```
onClick='document.title = "My new title";window.print();'
```

Comment: Wow that is quick. How do I combine the ahref and the onclick because I cant have twice the window.print. Or can I.

Comment: @Neal - I did the following: `<a href="javascript:window.print()" onClick='document.title = "My new title";'><img src="images/print.png" border="0"</a>` It is working now. Thank you very much.